# CSS tricks for IE like media screen does not work properly

Tags: css

I have read that `@media screen` and (`max-width: 800px`) should work for IE normally but in IE8 it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to fix it? change it? or make different syntax?

I also tried @media screen\0 and (max-width: 800px) and different possibilities

Comment: CSS3 is not supported by IE8 or less...you can do some polyfills...the question is why do you even want it to be Responsive on IE8?

Comment: Why do you even care about <IE9 visitors? (Haha)

Comment: my boss has strict standards everything should work everywhere anytime iam not even trying explain it to him anymore :DD I quess ill try grab some js

Comment: For IE8 ,usually it is javascript use to toggle a class to body so different style can be applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to increase the backwards comparability of your responsive design, such as for browsers like ie8 or ie6 - you need to add some script such as [respond.js](http://www.javascriptoo.com/respond-js) which enables responsive web designs in browsers that don't support CSS3 Media Queries.

Comment: does not work in IE 8 :D but thx anyway

Comment: It does. I use it all the time. The very definition of the script is "A fast & lightweight polyfill for min/max-width CSS3 Media Queries (for IE 6-8, and more)" - read me: http://www.javascriptoo.com/respond-js/readme